# How I can set default browser manually with file or registry modification?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

How I can set default browser manually with file or registry modification?

Windows 10, x64.

Because Edge is corrupted and windows can not perform setting of default browser 
in usual way with clicking of button 'Set default' (name is only for example, it
 is differs in Windows).

Corrupted Edge affects this in some way.

So I need make some file or registry modification to et Chrome as default.

Do not want to reinstall Edge.

**SOLUTION**

Before setting run

```
sfc /scannow
```

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do potentially do this via Group Policy:

> Unfortunately, no simple Group Policy switch exists to do the trick, and the entire procedure is a bit longwinded. First, you have to manually set Internet Explorer as the default on a reference machine. Click **Start** and then **Settings > System > Default apps**. Under **Web browser**, you can configure Internet Explorer as the default.
>
> [image: Web Browser]
>
> Next, you have to export this setting to an XML file with the DISM tool that is shipped with Windows 10:
>
> ```
> Dism /Online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:\\server\share\defaultassociations.xml
> ```
>
> This commands exports all file associations on your reference computer to an XML file on a network share. Thus, you have to make sure that you didn’t modify other app associations that you don’t want to deploy in your network. By the way, you can also use the method described here to set Chrome or Firefox as the default browser.
>
> Finally, you can deploy this XML file with the Group Policy **Set a default associations configuration file**, which is located in **Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer**.
>
> [image: Group Policy Configuration]

(Source:  [Set Internet Explorer as the default browser in Windows 10 with Group Policy](https://4sysops.com/archives/set-internet-explorer-as-the-default-browser-in-windows-10-with-group-policy/))

Comment: 1-st step is not possible, Windows can not perform setting of default browser in usual way. Of IE or other.

Comment: In other words, you receive an error message when you attempt to change the default web browser?  What do you see?

Comment: Settings window disappears because of error without a message.

Comment: It sounds like your system has some lingering issues. Over the long term, you may want to run `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt to check the integrity of your system files. Until then, navigate to `Control Panel` > `Default Programs` > `Set your default programs`.  When the list on the left-hand side populates select `Chrome`, and then on the right-hand side choose `Set this program as default`.